# Bash - How can I execute a variable

Tags: bash, variables, execute

I am reading a file with lines like:

```
folder=abc
name=xyz
```

For some lines line I would like set a variable e.g `name=xyz` corresponding to the line I have read.

Cutting it down, with `name=xyz` and `folder=abc`, I have tried:

```
while read -r line; do
    $line
    echo $name
done < /etc/testfile.conf
```

This gives an error message `./test: line 4: folder=abc: command not found` etc.

I have tried `"$line"` and `$($line)` and it is the same. Is it possible to do what I whant?

I have succeeded by doing:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == 'folder'* ]]; then
        folder="$(echo "$line" | cut -d'=' -f 2)"
    fi
    if [[ "$line" == 'name'* ]]; then
        name="$(echo "$line" | cut -d'=' -f 2)"
    fi
done < /etc/testfile.conf
```

but this seems messy

Comment: What do you want to execute? `./test: line 4: folder=abc: command not found` means that there execution occurred, but failed, as there was no such an application. Really hard to tell what are you asking about.

Comment: You seem to be set up to discover `eval`, then (hopefully sooner than later) concluding that redefining your problem is probably better than actually using `eval`.

Comment: @Flash Thunder, I was trying to set the variable "folder" to "abc"

Comment: @oguz ismail, That does the trick for what I want and is easy to follow

Comment: @Poshi, Thanks, it looks like it works, but to my untrained eye, oguz ismail's solution seems easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for your sample, `declare` is the safest option:

```
while read -r line; do
  declare "$line"
done
```

```
$ echo "$folder"
abc
$ echo "$name"
xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct approach, use `eval`.

Different approach, try with `source` or `.`:

```
$ echo "$line"
folder=abc
$ . <(echo "$line")
$ echo "$folder"
abc
```

But probably the good answer will be to tackle the problem in a different way.

Comment: eval is your friend

Comment: "With friends like this, who needs enemies?"

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your approach a bit without resorting to `eval`.

```
while IFS="=" read -r name value; do
    case $name in
        folder) folder=$value ;;
        name) name=$value ;;
    esac
done < /etc/testfile.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

why not only source de file ?

```
$ . infile ; echo "$name"
xyz
```

Comment: The file is actually somewhat more complicated. Divided into sections with xml type tags, and I only want a couple of values from each section. Thanks